# Discarding pixels in ps_2_0?

Tags: shader, hlsl, pixel-shader

Everything I looked up online indicates it does microsoft documents etc (but doesn't mention version)... but when I do this code:

```
float4 main(in float4 mXYZ : POSITION,in float4 mColor : COLOR0,in float2 mUV : TEXCOORD0): COLOR0
        {
            float4 pixel;
            pixel=mColor;
            if (ShouldDiscard(mUV)) {discard;}
            else return pixel;
    }
```

the compile tells me:

```
error X3004: undeclared identifier 'discard'
```

Am I doing some wonky syntax here?  Or do you have to discard some other way in PS_2_0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found it myself... for posterity, in older HLSL, discard can be accomplished with "clip(-1);"